# How can I automatically timestamp rows in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I am entering data into a Google Sheet. I would like to have a column where each row will be automatically timestamped with the `DateTime` in which I entered (or last updated) the contents of the row.

I know that I can do this manually by adding `=now()` to a cell, which will record the timestamp. However, this will update on any change to the doc, so I then need to copy and `ctrl-shift-v` to paste back just the value.

Would be more ideal if there was a formula that I could paste down the column which would only set `now()` as the value if there is a change in any of the selected columns in the given row.

Thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Hi Simona, you need a script to do that, its called Google Apps Script. Do you have programming skills?

Comment: I have used some c# and javascript before, but am still learning. Eager to try out new things, not afraid of scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [`onEdit trigger`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) will add the date to the adjoining column:

### Code

*ES6/v8/arrow/shorthand if statement*

```
const onEdit = (e) => e.range.columnStart === 1 ? e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date()) : null
```

*classic*

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.columnStart === 1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

### Explained

It reads as follows:

- the script is only fired when an edit was made in column 1 (A)
- if in column A, then add the date into the adjoining cell
- else do nothing

You could use the [`Utilities class`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities) to format the date to the date/time notation

```
const onEdit = (e) => e.range.columnStart === 1 ? e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")) : null
```

but you can format the column from within the Google Sheet as well (*Format > Number > Date time*). Paste this script into the script editor (*Tools > Script editor*) and save. Now it should work.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!